# ExecutorService runnable never hits try when an Exception occurs

Tags: java, java-8, lwjgl

I am trying to use a `CompletableFuture<T>` to respond to a LWJGL OpenGL context being created. This is done by calling the `open` method on `LWJGLGameWindow`. Here is the concerning code:

```
  @Override
  public CompletableFuture<?> open() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> {
      future.completeExceptionally(new TimeoutException("Could not establish contact with LWJGL"));
    }, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    scheduledExecutorService.execute(() -> {
      try {
        display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(defaultWidth, defaultHeight));
        display.create();
        future.complete(null);
      } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
      }
    });
    return future;
  }
```

The idea is to defer the creation of a display on a scheduled executor service. This is set up to be a single threaded scheduled executor service, because OpenGL contexts are thread-bound. If it takes too long to connect to LWJGL, then the returned future will break out of itself early.

The problem is that in unit tests, this works absolutely swimmingly. However, when I try and debug the program, any call to any of the `display` methods results in a real exception being thrown by lwjgl (because my library for lwjgl is not linked. This is still thrown as a `LwjglException`, though). For some reason, this exception is not picked up from the try-catch in this code here, and instead the exception is swallowed; the `future` never gets completed exceptionally.

So somewhere along the line, my exception is being swallowed in this code.

NB: `display` is simply a interface around LWJGL's `Display` - no fancy magic going on there. `scheduledExecutorService` is a single threaded scheduled executor.

I also appreciate that `.submit()` and `schedule` on `scheduledExecutorService` both return `Future<T>` but this lacks the composition I would like to use from `CompletableFuture<T>`. I'd like to be able to keep using that if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code actually works exactly as it should. The real problem is that the error I was expecting, `java.lang.UnsatisifiedLinkError`, is not an `Exception` but actually an `Error`. Amending the code to catch a `Throwable` solves this issue.